# R - Knit - Code Block - Failure

Tags: r, knitr, devtools

I have been trying to use knit in R to include a code block into a vignette 
(which was setup using devtools code):

```
use_vignette("Quickstart", pkg="../simTools")
```

However despite the function (sampleFromData from Sam's R in 24 Hours) being available I get the following error

Code in Quickstart.rmd:

`````
````{r}
library(mangoTraining)
example1 <- sampleFromData(demoData, size=5)
example1
````
`````

> Error processing file: Quickstart.Rmd Quitting from lines 35-38
>   (Quickstart.Rmd)  Error in sampleFromData(demoData, size = 5) :
>   could not find function "sampleFromData" Calls:  ... handle
>   -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval 
>   -> eval
>
> Execution halted

Any help appreciated!

Comment: you need to load whatever package sampleFromData is from. I have no idea... you might try `??sampleFromData`; also consider adding print(search()) right before that line to check the search path & be sure the right packages are loaded

Comment: What do you mean that `sampleFromData` is available? Why do you think it's available? What have you done to make it available? You've shown nothing to make it seem like it's available...